# Difference between String.getBytes() and Bytes.toBytes(String data)

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm writing a Hadoop/HBase job. I needed to transform a Java `String` into a byte array. Is there any differences between Java's `String.getBytes()` and Hadoop's `Bytes.toBytes()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [its documentation `Bytes.toBytes()`](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/util/Bytes.html#toBytes%28java.lang.String%29) converts the parameter to a `byte[]` using UTF-8.

[`String.getBytes()` (without arguments)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) will convert the `String` to `byte[]` using the platform default encoding. That encoding can vary depending on the OS and user settings. Use of that method should generally be avoided.

You could use [`String.getBytes(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) (or [the `Charset` variant](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29)) to *specify* the encoding to be used.

Answer (score 8):

Reading the Javadoc, it appear that String.getBytes() returns a `byte[]` using the default encoding and Bytes.toBytes() returns a `byte[]` using `UTF-8`

This could be the same thing, but it might not be.

Its always useful to read the Javadoc if you want to know something. ;)